# FB.getLoginStatus returns status unknown

Tags: ios, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am using cordova facebook plugin  for ios .

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
});

FB.login(
    function(response)
{});
```

i am getting this error `{"status":"unknown","authResponse":null}`

Answer (score 0):

As stated in Facebook document, FB.getLoginStatus will return with three possible responses:

- The user is logged into Facebook and has authenticated your
  application (connected)
- The user is logged into Facebook but has not    authenticated your
  application (not_authorized)
- The user is not logged into Facebook at this time and so we don’t
  know if they’ve authenticated your application or not (unknown).

```html
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
           if (response.status === 'connected') {
              // the user is logged in and has authenticated your app
              // show Open Graph related features here. Such as Frictionless sharing
           } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
              // the user is logged in to Facebook, but has not authenticated your app
              // show user Facebook status
           } else {
               // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
               // Hide all Facebook status mockups.
           }
        });
```

Comment: but i am getting {"status":"unknown","authResponse":null}

Comment: That means you have not logged into your app with Facebook credentials yet. please check

Comment: but i logged in from iphone->setting->facebook-my id and password means i loggedin

Comment: Try these two things:  1. Delete the facebook App from device and then try 2. Delete the facebook credentials from setting and then try

Comment: I am getting the same issues, please check this question and suggest some checklist http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40087845/facebook-plugin-not-works-after-installing-facebook-application